# Restack a crosstabulation to long, multi-index, Cartesian product, self join?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Taking the table, a crosstabulation read in from excel into pandas - I want to perform the re-arrangment:

```
    0       1   2       3       4       5
0   row_name    col_a   col_b       col_c       col_d       col_e
1   label_1     0.3 0.106628494 0.049496617 0.029875719 0.029444018
2   label_2     0.4 0.287788288 0.016961146 0.014512181 0.012937216
3   label_3     0.5 0.428264132 0.317066974 0.046346238 0.005149056
4   label_4     0.6 0.176474306 0.134044892 0.12476623  0.062386211
5   label_5     0.7 0.015996073 0.00574499  0.005136634 0.000789726
```

I am trying to get the long version of the table that is the intersection of column 0 and row 0

```
0   row_name    col_name    value
1   label_1     col_a       0.3
2   label_1     col_b       0.106628494
3   label_1     col_c       0.049496617
4   label_1     col_d       0.029875719
5   label_1     col_e       0.029444018
6   label_2     col_a       0.4
7   label_2     col_b       0.287788288
8   label_2     col_c       0.016961146
9   label_2     col_d       0.014512181
10  label_2     col_e       0.012937216
11  label_3     col_a       0.5
12  label_3     col_b       0.428264132
13  label_3     col_c       0.317066974
14  label_3     col_d       0.046346238
15  label_3     col_e       0.005149056
```

This is like a row by row pivot or possibly and self cartesian join - I'm not entirely sure.

I've tried `pd.wide_to_long()`   and `pd.stack()`  and neither is dead on, I was hoping for someone to point me in the right direction

It feels like I want to pivot only certain rows and make a multi-index out of 1 row and 1 column, but I haven't found a search query to satisfy the results.

Comment: you have your row headers included in the data frame as data, instead of actual column labels. is that intentional? `pd.stack` will work if you make your headers the actual column labels and you set the "row_name" column as the index.

Comment: yea it was intentional, at the time.   I will try what you suggested thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is a duplicate,
But you are looking for a melt function

```
df_melt=df.melt(id_vars="row_name")
```

Comment: thanks, I will try this, i figured it was a duplicate.